# Dropping Columns which have same values but different names

Tags: python, pandas

Currently merging two data frames where some of the columns of the two dataframes are the same  but not all.

```
 df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', on='name' )
```

This returns:

```
index   name  val1_x  val2_x  val1_y  val2_y
0      name1   1       2       1        3      
2      name2   12      14      12       34   
3      name3   14      3       14       96
```

But I would like:

```
index   name  val1_x  val2_x   val2_y
0      name1   1       2         3      
2      name2   12      14        34   
3      name3   14      3         96
```

How could you get this result? Either with the merge command or after?

--------- Extension - outer merge -------------

With an inner merge

```
df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='name', on='address').T.drop_duplicates().T
```

works as suggested in the solutions

However with an outer merge

```
df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='outer', on='name' )
```

It does not work since there are nan values. It returns

```
index   name  val1_x  val2_x  val1_y  val2_y
0      name1   1       2       nan      3      
2      name2   12      14      12       34   
3      name3   14      3       14       96
```

But I would like:

```
index   name  val1_x  val2_x   val2_y
0      name1   1       2         3      
2      name2   12      14        34   
3      name3   14      3         96
```

How can one achieve this?

Comment: `df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', on='name' ).drop(columns = 'val1_y')`?

Comment: How about column filtering before the merge? `df_1.merge(df_2[['name','val2']], how='outer', on='name')`

Comment: @ScottBoston real data has 50 cols dont want to have to harcode that

Comment: What if ```val1``` would be same as ```val2``` would you drop duplicates then as well? Or do you want to inner merge, keeping columns of the same name from both df-s, only if they are different, and keeping one, if they're the same? Can you also post your starting data i.e. ```df_1``` and ```df_2```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated aggregation, so you can just write your own function to resolve the groups. This method will only work to resolve numeric (datetime and Bool also work) data. With strings, you'll need to fall back to a much slower `pd.nunique` call over the rows.

For each group, we check if the columns are completely duplicated (using np.unique, after filling) and then either return the original group or the deduplicated grouping.

#### Starting Data

```
   index   name  val1_x  val2_x  val1_y  val2_y
0      0  name1       1       2     NaN       3
1      2  name2      12      14    12.0      34
2      3  name3      14       3    14.0      96
```

#### Code

```
l = []
for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1):
    if any(gp.dtypes == 'O') | (gp.shape[1] == 1):  # Can't/don't resolve these types
        l.append(gp)
    else:
        arr = np.unique(gp.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1).to_numpy(), axis=1)
        if arr.shape[1] == 1:
            l.append(pd.DataFrame(index=gp.index, columns=[idx], data=arr))
        else:
            l.append(gp)

df = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
```

---

```
   index   name  val1  val2_x  val2_y
0      0  name1   1.0       2       3
1      2  name2  12.0      14      34
2      3  name3  14.0       3      96
```

Comment: my data isn't only numeric also contains datetime

Comment: @Tank datetimes and Bool also work because they have numeric representations. You basically just can't have strings. If that's the case you use `pd.Series.nunique` but it will be slow since you need to apply that to every row. `np.unique` on the other hand will be very fast.

Comment: thank you, it works but you have to deal with NaN values before you merge

Comment: also surprised there is not a nicer way to do this - as in that requires one to write a personalized function

Comment: @Tank It's a combination of small things. Grouping over the columns axis is often messier. In addition, your aggregation either returns the original group or a collapsed grouping. This difference in size makes things messy (groupby works well when everything either remains the same size, or collapses to the same level, neither of which is the case here). And finally, the de-duplication involves some filling logic. Each part isn't that bad, but together they become messy. You can always move the logic to some function then just call it as `df = dedup_cols(df)`

Answer (score 2):

Use drop_duplicates

`df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', on='name' ).T.drop_duplicates().T`

```
  index   name val1_x val2_x val2_y
0     0  name1      1      2      3
1     2  name2     12     14     34
2     3  name3     14      3     96
```

Comment: added an extension